# setTimeout not changing external variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

Can anybody explain to me why the following code is producing an infinite loop?

```
var car = 'Ford';       
var done = false;

setTimeout(function() {     
    car = 'Toyota';
    done = true;
}, 500);

while (!done) {}
alert(car);
```

**Update:**
Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986444/return-variable-after-settimeout/#19986567) as well.

Comment: The duplicate question should provide you with an answer, but why are you doing this anyway? Surely you just want to get rid of the `while` loop and move the `alert` into the `setTimeout` callback function

Comment: My actual code has something similar but encased inside of a function, and the alert is meant to be a return statement. I just tried simplifying it to serve as a clearer example.